# Message from Businesslogic

Tags: jsf-2

how do you design your JSF application? Is there somewhere a good reference?

My approach is that I have a JSF layer where the view is managed, a Business layer where the business logic is implemented and a DB layer where i get my data from.

Problems with this approach are:

The business logic "field not empty" is in my EL. 
Another problem is when I validate in the business layer, I have to inform the JSF layer which error occur so the JSF layer can generate a JSF message.

How to handle such problems in an elegant way? (Or am I just wrong with my layers?)

Greetings